# Change background color dynamically and use a border

Tags: android

I have the following template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/borders" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_starred_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rating_not_important"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/category_starred_icon"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="@string/category"  />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i get a warning `This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless; transfer the background 
 attribute to the other view`, i want solve it, but i have the follow problem i have a border in the LinearLayout is like a drop shadow but when i change the background color in my code

```
mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.paseColor(mColorString));
```

i lost the border, how i can solve the warning witout lose the border, the main problem is **the background colors are dynamically**

Comment: you can remove the linear layout and use just the relative layout and set `android:background="@drawable/borders"` to relative layout

Comment: yeah but i need show both `android:background="@drawable/borders"` and backgroundColor set by code

Comment: i don't think its possible for the same layout

Comment: `mLayout` is LinearLayout or RelativeLayout Object? The warning is a lint warning

Comment: and yes the warning is a lint warning

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

This is an drawable that organizes other drawables in a layer list (one on top of the other). With it, you can use other drawables, like shape, to define the borders and the background the way you want.

I can't make a complete answer now, but if you search for this, I'm sure you can do it. When I have more time, I may come back to help you, if you haven't found out how to solve this yet.